# ¿Por qué se dice que no hay que abusar de las excepciones?

Tags: java-8, excepciones

Leí por ahí que en lo posible es conveniente evitar el uso de excepciones. Quisiera saber por qué, o en qué casos no conviene, ya que estoy desarrollando un programa y vengo haciendo uso de ellas, pero al enterarme de esto me veo en la disyuntiva de **controlar** o utilizar **excepción**.

Las que vengo utilizando son:

- **NumberFormatException**

  para parsear un String que viene de un JTextField.
- **Exception**

  para crear una fecha LocalDate con un String que viene de un JTextField.
- **ConstraintViolationException**

  en consultas a la base de datos mysql.

Las cuales me viene bárbaro ya que me evito un montón de comprobaciones y además me imprime la causa del error (aunque sé que no es adecuado para el usuario). Y por sobre todo me da mayor confianza, dado que a mí se me puede escapar algo, y se supone que a la máquina virtual no.

Entonces en mi caso, que me conviene?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se quiere decir con lo de no abusar del uso de las excepciones se refiere a que no hay que controlar todas y cada una de las excepciones que puede lanzar una aplicación. Para saber cuales se deben controlar hay que seguir unos criterios:

- Frecuencia con la que se produce una excepción (si es muy poco probable que se produzca y se produce por un "uso indebido de la aplicación*" no se debería comprobar, si usas mal mi aplicación ajo y agua).
- Conveniencia de control de la excepción: normalmente cuando capturas una excepción es porque quieres hacer algo con ella. Un ejemplo muy típico es cuando pides al usuario dos números a sumar y va y te mete sin querer alguna letra, tu capturas la excepción y le pides que vuelva a ingresar un número. Otro es el Login, es muy típico usar excepciones personalizadas tipo AccesDeniedException o UserNotFoundException. Ya que es mucho más correcto volver a pedirle los datos a que le devuelva una pantalla con Error 500 en el servidor (¡con uso normal de la aplicación esta pantalla hay que evitarla a toda costa!)
- Importancia de la excepción (o relevancia): Piensa que cada excepcion que controlas es tiempo y código dedicado exclusivamente a esa Excepción, luego en una empresa eso equivale a dinero. Hay que hacer un balance entre los criterios aquí mencionados para controlar la excepción y el tiempo y dinero que va a repercutir su control. (Muchas veces es mejor que una aplicación falle a perder un mes de trabajo para que no lo haga, cuando sí que debería fallar porque, por ejemplo, yo soy un usuario malicioso, te intento hackear y me estás dando reintentos para seguir haciéndolo).

*Uso indebido de la aplicación: se refiere a comportamiento del usuario malicioso con la aplicación, es decir, que intenta hacerle fallar o acceder de manera maliciosa, no porque se confunda.

Respecto a tu comentario, lo que digo precisamente en el punto 3 es lo que me comentas en el código, yo cuando digo controlar una excepción exclusivamente no me refiero a hacer `catch (Exception e)`, me refiero a hacer a hacer un `catch` para cada una de los tipos de excepciones que se pueden dar a una aplicación. Luego si no te interesa perder ese tiempo para controlar todos los tipos de excepciones, el `catch (Exception e)` es un escape, pero no se recomienda.

Ya que dentro del `catch` vas a hacer un comportamiento común para absolutamente todas las excepciones que pueda tirar el código encapsulado en el `try`. Vamos a poner un ejemplo:

Tú imagínate que tengo un programa que dada una fecha y el número de días que tú me digas, yo te calculo en que día estaríamos tras ese número de días  desde esa fecha. Ej. Fecha: 24/11/2019 Días a sumar: 7 Resultado: 1/12/2019. En esta aplicación no es nada recomendable utilizar sólo un `catch (Exception e)`, ya que te puede fallar el parseo de la fecha por un lado (`DateFormatException`) y el parseo de los días (`NumberFormatException`). Si tu usas `catch (Exception e)` cómo mucho puedes decirle al usuario ("Los datos introducidos no son correctos") y yo como usuario te pregunto: ¿Cual de los dos?¿Los dos?. Sin embargo, si tu separas el código en dos `catch` ( `catch(NumberFormatException e1)` y `catch(DateFormatException e1)`) tu aplicación tiene la capacidad de decir, si se produce un `NumberFormatException` "Los días introducidos no es número válido" y si se produce una `DateFormatException` "La fecha introducida no es válida", lo cual en aspectos de usabilidad es mucho más correcto. Ahora bien, ¿está totalmente bien sólo meter estos dos tipos de `catch`y quedarnos así? En absoluto, NO, nos falta un `catch (Exception e)`. **Siempre después de los otros catch por si se produjera un error que no podemos/queremos controlar de manera exclusiva:** Por ejemplo: Si esta aplicación es online, que se caiga el internet y no se pueda seguir ejecutando el código (ya sé que es un ejemplo muy básico y tal vez este caso no sea el más adecuado para meter el caso del internet, pero es un ejemplo). Este último `catch (Exception e)` estaría muy bien para meter un mensaje tipo: "El servicio no está disponible en este momento, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde" ¿te suena ese mensaje?, ya sabes cómo se suele hacer :D, es una manera de decir: "no sabemos que ******* has hecho pero has hecho fallar la aplicación, ya lo arreglaremos cuando podamos".

**IMPORTANTE**: siempre que vayas a hacer varios `catch`y uno sea `catch (Exception e)`, este último siempre tiene que ser el último, ya que java es un lenguaje síncrono y actúa en función de lo que se va encontrando en el código, es decir, ejectuan los `catch`en el orden que aparecen, y si el primero no captura la excepción que se está produciendo, lo intenta con el segundo, y si no con el tercero. El `catch (Exception e)` es el comodín para capturar cualquier excepción.

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta, pero sigo con dudas. Respecto al 2º punto, esa excepción (`NumberFormatException`) es una de las que mencioné que utilizo, y si quiero puedo `controlar`, en vez de usar `excepción`, pero había optado por usar `excepción` ya que me ahorraba tiempo y código.  Respecto al 3º punto, contrariamente a lo que decís, usar `excepciones` me ahorran tiempo y código, además de darme mayor confianza por que le delego esa tarea a la máquina virtual (o como se llame) que se supone que no va a fallar.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta para responderte :)

Comment: Recuerda que la pregunta esta "basada en opiniones" , te sugerimos revisar [ask] y [answer] @chikebox , saludos.